# Ajax request failing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve json data from an api.
It keeps failing, but when I look in the Net tab of Firebug I can see that the GET request executed and returned the correct data. Am I doing something wrong or does anyone have tips on how to debug this?

Edit: Have changed to dataType json and error status code is 0

Thanks

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:55894/api/Test/All',
        data: {
            format: 'json'
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Ok');
        },
        type: 'GET'
    });
```

Comment: Wow ok thanks everyone I just figured it out. Just had to change the dataType to script. I'm such a newbie :) Appreciate the responses

Comment: Why would he want a synchronous request? AJAX stands for **asynchronous** javascript and xml.

Comment: @juliet Change the `dataType` to the type of data you expect from the server.

Comment: What fails? what error are you getting? or is your alert just not getting called?

Comment: @Chausser It is no longer failing after I changed the dataType to script. My problem now is the data in "success: function(data)" is undefined

Comment: Thats because its expecting your returned data to be of type "script", if your server is returning json then just use the data type "json" without the "p"

Comment: @Chausser When I change to dataType json it fails with status code 0

Comment: Ok, then are you sure that your script is working? Have you tested it with other tools to confirm its working? If so then are you sure that the server is sending the data back with the proper headers? IE if it is JSON then `Content-Type: Application/JSON`. If both of those are as expected then we will need to see what the response body of the request is. In addition to the status Code

Comment: @Chausser When I go directly to the API URL the JSON it returns is correctly formatted (I checked in a validator), and yes it does have Content-Type: Application/JSON. Is it worth mentioning I am running the API and the website on different ports of local host?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70082/discussion-between-chausser-and-juliet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the info you provided the reason it is failing is because you dont have a cross domain access policy setup. Because you are using different ports to host the website and the API you are running into this issue. You can either setup a crossdomain.xml with the proper security settings or you can move both the API and the webserver to the same port.

Have a look at this for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you are a lifesaver! All working now with data returning nicely ^_^

Answer (score 0):

u can try this way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'url api here',
    beforeSend: function() {
    },
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(xhr) { // if error occured

    },
    complete: function() {

    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` and `JSONP` are different. If you are using `JSONP`, the server side must be prepared to support it. Doesn't look like you are using `JSONP`.

So just change `dataType` to `'json'`, as you are "trying to retrieve json data".